# no theme found for specified theme id . returning the default theme

Tags: templates, themes, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

By liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1 on theme folder I created a theme for my liferay portal 6.1.1 CE-GA2.

My liferay-plugin-package :

```
    name=internal_portal
module-group-id=liferay
module-incremental-version=1
tags=
short-description=
change-log=
page-url=http://www.liferay.com
author=Liferay, Inc.
licenses=LGPL
liferay-versions=6.1.1
```

---

```
My liferay-look-and-feel :

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE look-and-feel PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Look and Feel 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-look-and-feel_6_1_0.dtd">

<look-and-feel>
<compatibility>
<version>6.1.1</version>
</compatibility>
<theme id="internal_portal" name="internal_portal" />
</look-and-feel>
```

---

but after starting up my liferay portal, and after using my portal I see no theme found for specified theme id . returning the default theme in my liferay portal console.

How can I solve this issue?????????

Comment: Refer the following link http://goo.gl/yEfPsD

Answer (score 4):

Try to set this propertiy in your portal-ext.properties and restart your server:

```
#
# Set the default theme id for regular themes.
#
default.regular.theme.id=internal_portal
```

---

I recommend, however, to check the correct id of your theme from the control panel in the section

> Plugins Configuration **->** Theme Plugins

click on your theme and you will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: I see my theme ID in the location you provided.  Where/what do I change to the correct ID?

Answer (score 3):

Another very confusing cause for the "no theme found for specified theme id" error on Liferay 6.2 is if the id for your theme in liferay-look-and-feel.xml ends with "-theme".  This will cause portlets that use the CKEditor to request the wrong theme id when you try to edit their content, e.g. if you try to edit a Wiki entry or Web Content portlet's content.  For example, if the id in liferay-look-and-feel.xml looks like this:

`<theme id="example-theme" name="Example Theme" />`

editing a web content portlet will cause the portlet to request the theme ID example_WAR_exampletheme. However, the actual ID for the theme as referenced in the layout and layoutset tables in the database is exampletheme_WAR_exampletheme. Since there is no theme with an ID of example_WAR_exampletheme, the default theme will be returned. This results in SASS compilation errors because Compass is looking in the wrong place for files, which will cause 404 errors on CSS files. So if you're seeing "no theme found for specified theme id" followed by SASS compilation errors in the logs and you're getting 404s on CSS files and, make sure you don't have "-theme" on the end of your id in liferay-look-and-feel.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check console when the war for your theme is build ? were there any error there ?
While your theme is deployed in tomcat check the console there should be some errors / problem that is causing the above error message.

I hope you have gone through Theme Development Overview in below link. 
So in your theme you would have created _diffs folder having your custom css, images, js, templates.

https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-them-7

Answer (score 0):

As changing the `portal-XXX.properties` to force the use of a theme can be a solution. First, check your portal configuration settings using the UI. Probably you have removed a theme from Liferay and still is used in the portal.

Check this configurations:

> Configuration -> *Portal Settings*
>
> The in the lateral menu, check in your portal for *Display Settings*.
>
> And in Display Settings you have the option *Default Theme* and *Default Control Panel Theme*.

Check this last two options. Maybe are pointing to a unexisting theme. Change it to `Classic`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with these errors:

```
WARN  [http-bio-3000-exec-69][ThemeLocalServiceImpl:156] No theme found for specified theme id My_Theme_WAR_MyThemetheme. Returning the default theme.
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: aui/alloy-font-awesome/scss/mixins-alloy.
Load paths:
  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/html/css/common
  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/My_Theme-theme/html/themes/classic/css
  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/sass
  file:C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  file:C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  Compass::SpriteImporter
            import at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67
     imported_file at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28
       css_import? at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37
      visit_import at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:217
              send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097
             visit at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37
             visit at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100
    visit_children at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53
           collect at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2318
    visit_children at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53
    visit_children at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109
  with_environment at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121
    visit_children at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108
             visit at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37
        visit_root at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:128
              send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097
             visit at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37
             visit at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100
              send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097
             visit at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7
            render at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20
           _render at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/engine.rb:315
            render at file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/engine.rb:262
            (root) at <script>:48
18:16:12,505 ERROR [http-bio-3000-exec-29][DynamicCSSFilter:182] Unable to parse SASS on CSS /css/dockbar_vertical.css
com.liferay.portal.kernel.scripting.ScriptingException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (SyntaxError) File to import not found or unreadable: aui/alloy-font-awesome/scss/mixins-alloy._Load paths:  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/html/css/common  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/My_Theme-theme/html/themes/classic/css  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/sass  file:C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets  file:C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets  Compass::SpriteImporter [Sanitized]
    at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.eval(RubyExecutor.java:254)
    at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.eval(RubyExecutor.java:129)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.dynamiccss.DynamicCSSUtil._parseSass(DynamicCSSUtil.java:509)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.dynamiccss.DynamicCSSUtil.parseSass(DynamicCSSUtil.java:178)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.dynamiccss.DynamicCSSFilter.getDynamicContent(DynamicCSSFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.dynamiccss.DynamicCSSFilter.processFilter(DynamicCSSFilter.java:209)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor360.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy611.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.aggregate.AggregateFilter.processFilter(AggregateFilter.java:518)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor360.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy611.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor360.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy611.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (SyntaxError) File to import not found or unreadable: aui/alloy-font-awesome/scss/mixins-alloy._Load paths:  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/html/css/common  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/My_Theme-theme/html/themes/classic/css  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/sass  file:C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets  file:C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets  Compass::SpriteImporter [Sanitized]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.eval(RubyExecutor.java:248)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (SyntaxError) File to import not found or unreadable: aui/alloy-font-awesome/scss/mixins-alloy._Load paths:  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/html/css/common  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/My_Theme-theme/html/themes/classic/css  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/sass  file:C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets  file:C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets  Compass::SpriteImporter [Sanitized]
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:127)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1231)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1224)
    at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.doEval(RubyExecutor.java:189)
    at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor$EvalCallable.call(RubyExecutor.java:332)
    at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor$EvalCallable.call(RubyExecutor.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (SyntaxError) File to import not found or unreadable: aui/alloy-font-awesome/scss/mixins-alloy._Load paths:  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/html/css/common  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/My_Theme-theme/html/themes/classic/css  C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/sass  file:C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets  file:C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets  Compass::SpriteImporter [Sanitized]
    at Sass::Tree::ImportNode.import(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67)
    at Sass::Tree::ImportNode.imported_file(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28)
    at Sass::Tree::ImportNode.css_import?(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37)
    at Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform.visit_import(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:217)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097)
    at rubyjit.visit_A0E8B1FA377AB9D1DEC5F2DD57734F88312F36B9.visit(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37)
    at Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform.visit(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100)
    at rubyjit.visit_children_2CE1DD94F811FAA517E73B1DDDD68EFAF663D935.visit_children(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.collect(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2318)
    at rubyjit.visit_children_2CE1DD94F811FAA517E73B1DDDD68EFAF663D935.visit_children(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53)
    at Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform.visit_children(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109)
    at Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform.with_environment(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121)
    at Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform.visit_children(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108)
    at rubyjit.visit_A0E8B1FA377AB9D1DEC5F2DD57734F88312F36B9.visit(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37)
    at Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform.visit_root(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:128)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097)
    at rubyjit.visit_A0E8B1FA377AB9D1DEC5F2DD57734F88312F36B9.visit(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37)
    at Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform.visit(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097)
    at #<Class:0x5a10abe4>.visit(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7)
    at Sass::Tree::RootNode.render(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20)
    at Sass::Engine._render(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/engine.rb:315)
    at Sass::Engine.render(file:/C:/myproject/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ruby-gems.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/engine.rb:262)
    at #<Class:0x510084bc>.(root)(<script>:48)
```

Changing the name of Theme, removing "_" and "-", as I read in a previous post, solved it.